# How do I add shipping values per item?

Tags: html, paypal, joomla

I am using Joomla for my website which has some items for sale. I have hard coded the paypal buttons and costs for this and it works well:

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
    <input alt="Add this item to your order" name="submit" src="/add-to-order.gif" type="image" />
    <input name="add" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
    <input name="business" type="hidden" value="name@name.co.uk" />
    <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Item name" />
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="500.00" />
    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="GBP" />
    <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-ShopCartBF" />
 </form>
```

However, I wanted to add shipping values per item. These will be different depending on region of delivery and item. Is this all handled in the back end paypal set up? Or do I need to pass in these values? Any advice would be great thanks as im unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that PayPal integration, which is very old (about 20 years), the variables available for shipping and everything else are all [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/). The cart upload command specifically is [explained here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart-upload/).

A current [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) is much different.